# How to float a video in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I would like work with the my iTunes floating in my bottom right of my screen while I'm working with illustrator, is that possible?

Comment: on what operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Mac, you can use [Afloat](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/22237):

[image]

and for Windows, you can use one of the many "Always on top" programs, such as [DeskPins](http://users.forthnet.gr/pat/efotinis/programs/deskpins.html):

[image]